# .effmach x86 failed to swtich from 64bits to 32 bits

Tags: windows, debugging, 64-bit, windbg

I use Windbg 64 bits to debug a program (32bits, langage C), this program contains exceptions.
In my program I recolte informations about exception occured, especialy ExceptionRecord and ContextRecord and I call batch file that call **cdb.exe** (64bits).
The line in batch file where I call **cdb.exe** is:

```
 cdb.exe -p %PID% -pd -loga %LogFile%.txt -lines  -c ".echo ;.echo *** Call stack of module causing abort ***;.effmach x86;.cxr %ContextRecord%;kp; .dump /ma %LogFile%.dmp;q" > nul
```

Where %PID% : my process Id
So, when I use ;**.load wow64exts;!sw;** instead **.effmach x86**, the debuger run and show me exactly what I need (The line and function caused exception), but when I use **.effmach x86**, the batch file stop runing, or crash, or I don't know, but there is no result and the logfile not created.
My question: Why **.effmach x86** crash my batch file?
Thanks

I use Windows 7 64 bits
(sorry for my english)

Comment: Since your program is 32, why do you not use 32 bits Windbg ?
As long as you do user mode this works perfect even on a 64 bits Windows.

Comment: Which version of WinDbg? Why do you actually .effmach - because you create a full dump anyway, which has all that information inside, so you can still do .effmach later?

Comment: Maybe you can debug CDB with WinDbg to find out :-)

Comment: Hi, Thank you all for your comments.  
@Kjell Gunnar : In this time we have a big migration to win7 64 bits, and i would test for 64 bits  
Thomas W : With WinDbg directly, it works perfectly, since I should use batch file for some reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have find problem
for simple reason, must add space between x86 and next semicolon ; (x86; architecture doesn' exist)